# Почему возникает ошибка авторизации Spring Security

Tags: java, html, spring-security

Если перевожу проект в рест, тестирую в постман, то он и регестрирует и авторизует пользователя. А при переходе на дефолтный контроллер он не авторизует....

`User class`

```
@Entit
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    private Boolean locked = false;
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    public User(String email, String username, String password, Role role) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority =
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }



    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

`UserService class`

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {


    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG =
            "user with email %s not found";
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
    }

    public String SignUpUser(User user){
        boolean userExists = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).isPresent();

        if (userExists){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken");
        }
        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "user signup";
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig class`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private final UserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
                .authorizeRequests()
                //Доступ только для не зарегистрированных пользователей
                .antMatchers("/register").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                //Доступ разрешен всем пользователей
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                //Все остальные страницы требуют аутентификации
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                //Настройка для входа в систему
                .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .usernameParameter("email")
             .passwordParameter("password")
                //Перенарпавление на главную страницу после успешного входа
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
             .logoutUrl("/logout")
             .invalidateHttpSession(true)
             .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

`RegistrationService class`

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final EmailValidator emailValidator;

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request){
        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());

        if  (!isValidEmail){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email is not valid");
        }

      return userService.SignUpUser(
              new User(
                      request.getEmail(),
                      request.getUsername(),
                      request.getPassword(),
                      Role.USER
              )
      );
    }

    public int enabledUser(String email){
        return userRepository.enableUser(email);
    }
}
```

`RegistrationRequest class`

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class RegistrationRequest {
        private String email;
        private String username;
        private String password;
}
```

`login form`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>


<p>New here? Click
    <a th:href="@{/register}">here</a> to register.</p>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/login}" id="login">
    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br/>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`registration form`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/register}" method="post" id="register">
    <label th:th:for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
    <label th:for="email" name="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <label th:for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <label th:for="confirm">Confirm password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .... какая ошибка?

Comment: ошибок нет, в браузере возникает login?error и всё.
всё, что выводится в консоли так это 
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_0_, user0_.locked as locked4_0_, user0_.password as password5_0_, user0_.role as role6_0_, user0_.username as username7_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.email=?